# sizeWithFont: and sizeWithAttributes: don't work for a long single line

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cell, row-height

I'm trying to set a dynamic height for cells in my table, height should be based on a text length and a max width.

The problem appears when this text comes in a single line, without line separators. Doesn't matter how large the text is, if there are no line separators it detects that text fits in a single line so my cell height doesn't increase.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I achieve it? Thanks.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat cellheight = 35.0f; // BASE

    NSString *text = @"...";

    if (text) {
    UIFont *font = (indexPath.row == 0) ? [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]; 
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);

    if (IS_EARLIER_THAN_IOS7) {
        CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
        cellheight += size.height;
    } else {
        CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]}];

        CGSize adjustedSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(size.width), ceilf(size.height));
        cellheight += adjustedSize.height;
    }
    return (indexPath.row == 0) ? cellheight + 40.0f : cellheight;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:") __TVOS_PROHIBITED; // NSTextAlignment is not needed to determine size
```

You should use "boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:" not "sizeWithAttributes:".

This is a sample

```
CGSize size = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(_myTableView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]} context:nil].size;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way more easy way to do that:

First set the text to the `UILabel`, and set all the required font, size. etc. Then call `sizeThatFits` method on the label.

> `CGSize sizze =[itemLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(itemNameLabelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];`

Also dont forget to set `numberOfLines` and `lineBreakMode` before calling `sizeThatFits:`

```
itemLabel.numberOfLines=0;
itemLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

**Note 1** : calling `sizeThatFits` does not set the new frame to the UILabel, it just calculates and returns the new frame. You have to then set the frame to the label by adding x and y origin values. So that becomes :

```
CGSize sizze =[itemLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(itemNameLabelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
CGRect namelabelFrame = itemLabel.frame;
namelabelFrame.size = sizze;
itemLabel.frame = namelabelFrame;
```

**Note 2** : This code is okay in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but when calculating the height inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` you may want to optimize this code a little bit. As you don't have the cell to work with you might initialize a `UILabel` object and perform this code on it to estimate the height. But having `UIView` initializations inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is not a good idea as they can significantly affect performance while scrolling.

So what you do is have an already initialised (and all formatting applied) `UILabel` as a class variable and reuse that for height calculation.

Comment: For calculate size for UILabel, using `sizeThatFits:` give more ideal size later than calculate from NSString's `boundingRectWithSize:`.